# Changing pickerview's value using a switch

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uiswitch

I have a couple of picker views and a switch. What I would like to do is change the values of the pickers every time the button is toggled. For simplicity, let's say that I want to select the second row of each picker when the switch is on, and select the tenth row of each picker when the switch is off. From what i gathered in the past couple of hours, the way to do this is as follows:

```
// action called when the switch is toggled
- (void) switchToggled:(id)sender {

if ([sender isOn]) {
    [picker1 selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; 
    [picker2 selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; 
  }
else {
    [picker1 selectRow:10 inComponent:0 animated:YES];    
    [picker2 selectRow:10 inComponent:0 animated:YES];    
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to working, though. I also noticed that the `selectRow:inComponent` method doesn't change the value of the picker unless it is called when the view is being drawn/redrawn, or when it's being called from the `didSelectRow:inComponent` method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are picker1 and picker2 IBOutlets and are they connected to the controls in the xib/storyboard?  Need to connect both the control and its delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectRow: inComponent: animated: has always worked to move the picker for me, and I've done stuff like this plenty. The thing that used to catch me out is that will trigger pickerview: didSelectRow: inComponent: on the delegate, which I generally only want called when the setting has come from the user, not from my own code.  The way to work around this is either

```
picker.delegate = nil;
[picker selectRow:foo inComponent:bar animated:probably];
picker.delegate = thatObjectWhichWasDelegateAsecondAgo;
```

Or have a bool ivar you cans set to no briefly eg listenToPicker, then inside didselectrow..

```
-(void)pickerview:pickerview didSelectRow:row inComponent:component{

if (listenToPicker){

///act on input


}}
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to solve the problem. Interestingly enough, when i try `NSLog(@"%@", picker.delegate);`, the output is (null), even though the delegate methods are being called when the value of the pickers are changed (by the user). Is this the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: I'll bet your pointers picker1 and picker2 are broken. (Have been nil'd out). The delegate is returning NULL because picker1 == nil.  There are pickers on the screen, sure and they have delegate/datasource, but your pointers are broken.  Try using self.picker1 and synthesizing a property (strong, nonatomic)

Comment: Try logging inside did select row...   if (pickerview != picker1 && pickerview != picker2){NSLog @"I am getting messages from a rouge pickerview!";} if this comes up you have a retain issue with your pointers as I surmised above, either retain them better or ditch the variables and get them with self.view viewWithTag:myConstantTagForPicker1 ....

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. I'm already using synthesized properties, and the didselectrow method functions correctly using the pointers, as I'm already using it. I even tried logging, and there's no problem.

Comment: Logging the delegate of each picker DOES return a value in the didselectrow method, though..

Comment: I solved the problem: The switches I'm using were being overlaid on a table, and were allocated in the tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath method. When the switches were allocated outside of this method, everything worked fine. Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

```
reloadAllComponents
reloadComponent:
```

these two methods are available for reloading the UIPickerview

make the changes to the datasource datatypes and call a reload then on the event on switch

Comment: You shouldn't need to reload the data in order to move the picker, no not at all..  And the dataSource does not tell the picker which row ought be selected in component x, it's not part of the protocol (not part of either of them actually)

Comment: I already tried that, and it still didn't work. I believe what Jef said is true: there's no need to reload the components to move the pickers.

Answer (score 0):

it should work.I have used the same method, it's working for me. The problem might be some where else..

Answer (score 0):

This has changed in ios9. It works if you use:

```
        picker.selectRow(rowNum, inComponent: componentNum, animated: true)
```